# Does it detect colour?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection

One year ago I trained a model to detect flowers. One year later I am starting this project up again, but first I decided to make sure I still remembered by training it to detect and red and green crayons.

My process is more or less following this tutorial – 
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

I have two labels, green and red. I have 200 training images and 20 test images. 
Using faster_rcnn_inception. I followed the steps and ran my model.

It detects the crayons as well as you could with only 200 images, however, can’t tell the red and green crayon apart at all. I thought maybe I had screwed up the settings, but if I move a blue pen in, the label pops up!

[image]

Even if I feed it the training images, it classifies 99% of them as two green pens. Even though each image always has two different pens!!!

Can this model work with colour? Or is it converting the colour somehow and messing it up? Is colour hard to detect, and I just need more training images? Have I likely screwed up a setting, since it can’t even correctly classify the training images?

The config file I am using is here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
I've changed line 9, line 130 and line 108 to false.

Answer (score 1):

In general, neural networks can detect colour.

[image]

But often they learn not to. Due to differences in colour temperature and perspective different colours can produce same or similar pixel-level values. Therefore, when training on larger datasets networks tend to become highly colour agnostic. Unfortunately, I can only speak from the gut feeling and can not provide any example or reference, but the picture above should give you a sense why.

In your case issues are further complicated by the fact, that there is a competing task of detecting object box. Due to that during retraining detection net can become insensitive to weak clues like colour.

To troubleshoot the situation I would recommend to look closely on your classification accuracy during retraining. As far as i can tell, tutorial code only provides loss value. One should expect that during retraining at least the train set should be overfit almost perfectly i.e. green and red crayons must become distinguishable. If not, it might make sense to train for longer or decrease the learning rate.